# Printing List inside a Hashmap onto a text file problems, follow-up

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, text-files

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67793343/how-can-i-update-specific-parts-of-a-text-file-in-java) question.

I currently have a List in a HashMap and am trying to print each entry onto a text file.
When the HashMap is printed, the file is displayed oddly as seen below. Im not sure what else i can do here.

**Input1:**

Name: Bob; goals: 1; assists: 2; games played: 3; etc...

**Input2:**

Name: ben; goals: 2; assists: 3; games played: 1; etc...

**Text file output:**

bob:[1 2 3 4 5 6 (2021/06/01 17:03:43)]

bob:[1 2 3 4 5 6 (2021/06/01 17:03:43), 2 3 1 3 2 1 (2021/06/01 17:03:54)]

ben:[1 2 3 4 5 6 (2021/06/01 17:03:43), 2 3 1 3 2 1 (2021/06/01 17:03:54)]

**Expected OutPut:**

bob:[1 2 3 4 5 6 (2021/06/01 17:03:43)]

ben:[2 3 1 3 2 1 (2021/06/01 17:03:43)]

How can I fix this issue?
Also when i checked the index of each value in the list they all appeared -1, why is this?
Main:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;



public class TextReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("/Users/Coding/Desktop/myFile.txt").toAbsolutePath();
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             BufferedWriter fileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

            Reader reader = new Reader(path, fileWriter, fileReader);
            reader.menu();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Reader:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;

public class Reader {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();//Creating HashMap

    Path path;
    Scanner scan;
    BufferedWriter fileWriter;
    BufferedReader fileReader;
    List<String> playerData;


    Reader(Path path, BufferedWriter fileWriter, BufferedReader fileReader) {

        this.scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.path = path;
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
        this.fileReader = fileReader;
        this.playerData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void menu() throws IOException {
        String task;

        do{
            System.out.print("What would you like to do today?: ");
            task = scan.nextLine();
            switch (task) {
                case "1":
                    addData();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    updateData();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    fileWriter.close();
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }while(!task.equals("6"));
    }

    void addData(){
        boolean cont;

        DateTimeFormatter log = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
        String logTime = log.format(time);

        do try {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Player: ");
            String playerName = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Games Played: ");
            int gamesPlayed = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Goals Made: ");
            int goals = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Assists Made: ");
            int assists = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Points Scored: ");
            int points = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Saves Made: ");
            int saves = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Shots Made: ");
            int shotsOnGoal = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            playerData.add(
                    gamesPlayed + " " + goals + " " + assists + " " + points + " " +
                            saves + " " + shotsOnGoal + " (" + logTime + ")");
            System.out.println(playerData);

            dataMap.put(playerName,playerData);
            writeData();
            fileWriter.flush();

            cont = false;
        } catch(NumberFormatException | IOException e){
            System.out.println("Enter Valid Input");
            cont = true;
        }while(cont);


    }

    void writeData() throws IOException {
        try{

            //iterate map entries
            for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : dataMap.entrySet()){

                //put key and value separated by a colon
                fileWriter.write( entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue() );

                //new line
                fileWriter.newLine();
            }

            fileWriter.flush();

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void updateData() throws IOException {

    }


}
```

Comment: Your List playerData is keeping old information. I think the solution would be to not make playerData a global variable or, after adding playerData to your dataMap, remove all elements from playerData

Comment: If i clear both dataMap and playerData it is printed correctly onto the text file however my next method is supposed to update values which i cant do without access to the old data.

Comment: Don’t clear your dataMap, only clear your playerData List after you’ve added the player to the dataMap. Then you will have your dataMap with all your data. The playerData should only act as a placeholder for data essentially

Comment: Without clearing the dataMap when i add a new data set the previous one is added onto it: `bob:[1 2 3 4 5 6 (2021/06/01 20:03:13)]
bob:[1 2 3 4 5 6 (2021/06/01 20:03:13)]
ben:[1 5 3 8 5 3 (2021/06/01 20:03:54)]`

Comment: That’s very odd as you’re only ever adding a player once to the map in your addData() method. Here’s one solution: add an if statement - if(!dataMap.contains(playerName)) then dataMap.put(playerName, playerData). This will only add data if the name does not already exist in the map. However, this does mess with when there are duplicate names with different data. If you know that there will only ever be unique names, then this if statement might help. Otherwise, I’m unsure why dataMap has old data

Comment: i wrapped the if statement around the dataMap.put() and calling the writeData() method and several issues still come up

Comment: Sorry, I think I realized the problem. Ignore my last suggestion. You are calling the method writeData() too many times. You should only writeData() once you know that the user no longer wants to add more players. So in your switch/case in your menu() method, in case 6, you can call the writeData() method. I think this should fix it